# How to prevent/avoid duplicate row insert in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

here's my code snippet:

```
insert os
insert sys
insert pandas as pd

data=[['2019-04-04',1105],['2019-04-05',1145],['2019-04-06',1125],['2019-04-07',1130],['2019-04-08',1122],
      ['2019-04-09',1105],['2019-04-10',1145],['2019-04-11',1125],['2019-04-12',1130],['2019-04-13',1122],
      ['2019-05-04',1105],['2019-05-05',1145],['2019-05-06',1125],['2019-05-07',1130],['2019-05-08',1122],
      ['2019-05-09',1105],['2019-05-10',1145],['2019-05-11',1125],['2019-05-12',1130],['2019-05-13',1122]
      ]
pp=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','Price'])


def clear_screen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear') 

def print_menu():
    clear_screen()
    print("-"*15,"Menu","-"*15)
    print("1. Data display")
    print("2. Data insert")
    print("3. Data update")
    print("4. Data search")
    print("5. Data delete")
    print("6. Exit")
    print("-"*36)
 
def back2menu():
    print()
    input("Press Enter to back.")

loop=True

while loop:
    print_menu()
    choices=int(input("Insert choice[1-6]: "))

   if choices==1:
       clear_screen()
       print("Display data")
   elif choices==2:
        dt=input("Insert date: ")
        prc=int(input("Insert price: "))
        pp.loc[len(pp)]=[dt,prc]
        
        print("Data has been added.")
        
        back2menu()
   .....
   .....
   .....
   elif choices==6:
        print("You've exited from the program")
        loop=False
        sys.exit()
   .....
```

And here's the dataframe sample:

```
          Date  Price
0   2019-04-04   1105
1   2019-04-05   1145
2   2019-04-06   1125
3   2019-04-07   1130
4   2019-04-08   1122
5   2019-04-09   1105
6   2019-04-10   1145
7   2019-04-11   1125
8   2019-04-12   1130
9   2019-04-13   1122
10  2019-05-04   1105
11  2019-05-05   1145
12  2019-05-06   1125
13  2019-05-07   1130
14  2019-05-08   1122
15  2019-05-09   1105
16  2019-05-10   1145
17  2019-05-11   1125
18  2019-05-12   1130
19  2019-05-13   1122
```

I want to implement some input condition like this:

```
if the date is already exist in the dataframe:
    print("Error, because the data on this date already exist.")
else:
    #There you go, you can insert data
```

Is there any way to do it with pandas? Because i've been tried with `pp.drop_duplicates(subset='Date',keep='first')` it isn't work and the duplicated date still inputed to the dataframe like this:

```
          Date  Price
0   2019-04-04   1105
1   2019-04-05   1145
2   2019-04-06   1125
3   2019-04-07   1130
4   2019-04-08   1122
5   2019-04-09   1105
6   2019-04-10   1145
7   2019-04-11   1125
8   2019-04-12   1130
9   2019-04-13   1122
10  2019-05-04   1105
11  2019-05-05   1145
12  2019-05-06   1125
13  2019-05-07   1130
14  2019-05-08   1122
15  2019-05-09   1105
16  2019-05-10   1145
17  2019-05-11   1125
18  2019-05-12   1130
19  2019-05-13   1122
20  2019-05-13   555
```

and not like the first dataframe i showed.

Don't mind the price tho, i just want the date is not duplicated if i input the same date.

Comment: For your next question, you need to [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, read through the help section on [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your first section of code should not have been included. I didn't even read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date_str = '2019-05-14'
price = 1200

if any(pp['Date'] == date_str):
    print('Date already exists.')
else:
    pp.loc[len(pp)] = [date_str, price]
    print('New date added to dataframe.')
    
print(pp)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a condition like this

```
var = dataframe['date'][dataframe.duplicated(subset=['date'])] 

if len(var) >0:
            print("Error: Date is already present")
```

Here you can use print statement or raise error statement to generate error

Comment: The functionality of the DataFrame should be used. A DataFrame should not be converted to a list when it's not necessary.

Comment: I've edited the code you can take a look at it @Jakub

Comment: That's great code for finding duplicates. However, that doesn't solve the problem. blau_layar wants to determine if a date is already in the df before inserting it. With you're solution you would have to first insert date. blau_layar explicitly stated that drop_duplicates does not work how he wants.

Comment: Alternatively he can also use where condition of dataframe followded by dropna property of dataframe eg: ```dataframe.where(dataframe['Date']==value,inplace=True) ``` followed by  ```dataframe = dataframe.dropna(axis=0)``` and at last giving condition ```if len(dataframe) >0:
            print("Error: Date is already present")``` @Jakub